# Spark overwrite mode and concurrent execution

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a spark where I am using overwrite mode like:

```
  .repartition(10)
      .write
      .mode("overwrite")
```

This works fine, but due to some code bug we endup starting multiple concurrent execution of same job and endedup with duplicate data in the s3 folder.

- Is there a way to deal with concurrency and overwrite mode?

If no,

- Is there a way to fail fast?

Comment: Duplicate data might be due to s3 consistency due to failed task. Keep spark max attempts to 1, so it dont  retry.

Comment: @Achyuth Its more about "multiple concurrent execution of same job" as per OP has stated. How about you add a "dirty marker" somewhere? Or use something like Redisson to create a distributed lock on your S3 resources.

Comment: S3 is a distributed object store that works on the principle of eventual consistency. So where are you getting the idea that it is kicking off multiple jobs? How is your input df constructed?

Comment: One recommendation is write to hdfs and use s3-distcp it will be way faster. There is no concept of renaming in s3

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to deal with concurrency and overwrite mode?

not without some higher level co-ordination

> Is there a way to fail fast?

don't use overwrite

General convention is "write somewhere then rename into place", relying on rename being a fast atomic means of exclusively committing work. But as S3 doesn't work that way, you can't rely on that either.

Answer (score 0):

In Spark by default max attempt will be two. Set this to 1 in Spark Submit command --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1